# JavaScript plugin fire more than once

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I have a javascript plugin

```
;(function(window){
//some functions
function plugin(el, options){
}
plugin.prototype = {
//other functions
}
})(window);
```

however this is not so important.
Then I call this plugin like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tooltip]')
  for(i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
    new tooltipizeIt(el[0], { effect : 'fade-and-move', theme : 'custom', width : 200, position : 'right'});
    new tooltipizeIt(el[1], { theme : 'light', effect : 'fade', width : 120, position : 'top'});
    new tooltipizeIt(el[2], { effect : 'scale', theme : 'dark', position : 'bottom'});
    new tooltipizeIt(el[3], { effect : 'no-effect', theme : 'custom', position : 'top', width : 135});
    new tooltipizeIt(el[4], { effect : 'fade-and-move', theme : 'light', position : 'bottom', width : 400});
    new tooltipizeIt(el[5], { effect : 'fade-and-move', theme : 'light', position : 'left', width : 400, ajax : true});
  }
}, false);
```

As you see i called this plugin six times , but plugin fires six times for every `el` element, if I call it seven times, will fire seven time and so on.
known someone why and if is there a solution to fix this?

**EDIT**
I added one image , as you see plugin creates six tooltips for the same element 
[image]

Comment: And why wouldn't it, you're iterating over the elements, calling it six times for each element ?

Comment: if I call it like this `new tooltipizeIt(el[i], { effect : 'fade-and-move', theme : 'custom', width : 200, position : 'right'});`, once for every element it will fire once, but for example if i want to call it for tw elements, Eg `new tooltipizeIt(el[0], { //some options'});
    new tooltipizeIt(el[1], { //some other options});` first with some options and second with another options it will fire twice for every element , so 2*2 =4 time fires, is that right? if so my fold, i didn't know-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @adeneo it is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.
Because of your [for](/questions/tagged/for) loop it will always make `6*el.length` calls.

Specifically each of the first 6 elements with `data-tooltip` will have the same call happen to it 6 times. This is just the way [for](/questions/tagged/for) loops work.

For example, the first element will have this specific call happen 6 times:

```
new tooltipizeIt(el[0], { effect : 'fade-and-move', theme : 'custom', width : 200, position : 'right'});
```

While the second one will have this specific all happen 6 times:

```
new tooltipizeIt(el[1], { theme : 'light', effect : 'fade', width : 120, position : 'top'});
```

And so on.  If there is ever a 7th element it will not get called at all.  Likewise, if there are less than 6 elements attributes it will fail because you are directly accessing each one and `el[5]` will be `undefined`.

Here is a demonstration of how this kind of thing works but more detail will be needed to truly make your code do what you want.  Hopefully comparing this code to the output will help you to understand the concepts involved here.

```js
// This is a simple call to show some output
function log(message) {
  $("#log").text($("#log").text() + message + '\n');
}

//
// Here's the real stuff
//

// Create an array with six values, much like your example.
var el = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
log("el has " + el.length + " items in it.")

// Loop for as many items as there are in the array.
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  log("  This message is in the loop so it will happen " + el.length + " times.")
  log("  This message is also in the loop so it will also happen " + el.length + " times.")
}

log("");
log("That was " + el.length + " * 2 or " + (el.length * 2) + " messages.")

log("")
log("In your example you actually used each item but you didn't like this...")

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  log("  Do something to " + el[0] + ".")
  log("  Do a second something to " + el[1] + ".")
  log("  Do a third something to " + el[2] + ".")
  log("  Do a forth something to " + el[3] + ".")
  log("  Do a fifth something to " + el[4] + ".")
  log("  Do a sixth something to " + el[5] + ".")
}

log("");
log("That was " + el.length + " * 6 or " + (el.length * 6) + " messages.")

log("")
log("You wanted it to do 6 different things, leaving the loop out would do that.")


log("  Do something to " + el[0] + ".")
log("  Do a second something to " + el[1] + ".")
log("  Do a third something to " + el[2] + ".")
log("  Do a forth something to " + el[3] + ".")
log("  Do a fifth something to " + el[4] + ".")
log("  Do a sixth something to " + el[5] + ".")
  
log("");
log("That was 6  messages.")


log("")
log("Of course that only works if there are exactly 6 items.  Try to do that with 7 items and things get wonky.")


log("  Do something to " + el[0] + ".")
log("  Do a second something to " + el[1] + ".")
log("  Do a third something to " + el[2] + ".")
log("  Do a forth something to " + el[3] + ".")
log("  Do a fifth something to " + el[4] + ".")
log("  Do a sixth something to " + el[5] + ".")
log("  Do a seventh something to " + el[6] + ".")


log("")
log("This just showed undefined but in more complex code it might break all together.")

log("")
log("Had there been 7 items this would all have gone differently.")

el = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
log("el has " + el.length + " items in it.")

log("  Do something to " + el[0] + ".")
log("  Do a second something to " + el[1] + ".")
log("  Do a third something to " + el[2] + ".")
log("  Do a forth something to " + el[3] + ".")
log("  Do a fifth something to " + el[4] + ".")
log("  Do a six something to " + el[5] + ".")
  
log("");
log("That was still 6 messages because there were exactly 6 calls.")

log("  Do something to " + el[0] + ".")
log("  Do a second something to " + el[1] + ".")
log("  Do a third something to " + el[2] + ".")
log("  Do a forth something to " + el[3] + ".")
log("  Do a fifth something to " + el[4] + ".")
log("  Do a six something to " + el[5] + ".")
  
log("");
log("It is more likly that you intened to one thing to each item.")
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  log("  Do something to " + el[i] + ".")
}

log("");
log("That was " + el.length + " messages.")

log("");
log("Notice that the same thing was done to each item.")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

I think you are better off describing what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm not a javascript guru so thanks for your clear explanation , I get it now.